# Can I add modules to existing package from separate library?

Tags: python

There is code in a proprietary library (e.g. below, called `foo.bar`) that I use which loads modules at runtime like this:

```
module_name = f"foo.bar.{some_module}"
module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
```

The user supplies the name of a module in some text config and that module is loaded by the library.

I want to supply some modules which add additional functionality, so I'd like to write a separate library to add further modules to the `foo.bar` package and bundle these up for distribution via an internal PyPi.

So someone would run `pip install foo mylibrary` and this would install the `foo` and the `mylibrary` libraries, but I want the classes inside `mylibrary` to also appear inside the `foo.bar` namespace.

Is this possible please?

Comment: Well, inside `foo/bar.py` you can certainly do `from mylibrary import *`.  You would have to make `mylibrary` a dependency of `foo`.  In other words, you can't do this without modifying the `foo` package.

Comment: @TimRoberts That's incorrect, if `foo.bar` is already designed as a [namespace package](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) then this is certainly possible without modifying `foo`.

Answer (score 3):

You're describing the basic usage of namespace packaging.

If `foo.bar` is already a [namespace package](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/), then contribution of new submodules by 3rd-party packages is supported.

```
# in setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="mylibrary",
    ...
    namespace_packages=["foo.bar"]
)
```

Installing `mylibrary` is able to lay down new modules within the `foo.bar` namespace. Follow the guide on [packaging namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#packaging-namespace-packages) for more detailed information.

In your case, it does seems likely `foo` could already be using namespace packaging, since the dynamic importlib loading shown in the question suggests that it's intended to work with arbitrarily named "some_module" submodules, perhaps provided by 3rd party "plugins".

If the proprietary library `foo` is not already a namespace package, and it can't be converted into one, then this isn't <s>possible</s><sup>†</sup> recommended - a regular package <s>can not</s> should not inject modules into another package's path at install time.

<sup>†</sup><sub>Well, actually, it is *possible*. For example, installing the package *zen-of-numpy* will make available `import numpy.this` or `from numpy import this`, even though numpy itself is not a namespace package and doesn't provide a `this` submodule.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

As **@wim** points out, you often can't do this at install time, however, you can do this at runtime (though I would *never* recommend doing so because it will cause confusion and you will eventually regret it, it can be convenient for testing)

This is called "Monkey Patching" (see  [What is monkey patching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching))

```py
# /usr/bin/env python3
# source from mylib.py
import foo

def baz():
    ...

foo.bar = baz
```

Just import both packages at least once and the import of your custom library will modify `foo`

```py
import foo
import mylib
```

However, I again do not recommend doing this for anything other than testing ..

- What if `foo` updates and adds a function with the same name as one you're patching in? Now you'll clobber it and may break the updated `foo`!
- What if you want to publicly release your packages?
- What if a developer submits bugs in your package to the upstream `foo`?
  ...